# How to manage two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

i have two tables offer1 and offer2

The two tables are

```
Offer1 
Offer2ID|OfferName|OfferExpiryDate

Offer2
Offer2ID|OfferName|OfferExpiryDate
```

now i have third table which keeps record

```
offersentdetail 
offerID|senttime|sentCount|UserID
```

now i want output sent on Specifc userID

Output will be like

UserID | OfferID | OfferName

Comment: In your schema, there is currently no way to know if it's part of Offer1ID or Offer2ID. How are you making that distinction? Can those offerIds overlap? Is this really the schema?

Comment: Please include DDL statement fro your tables and sample data of each table, and output data that you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
select osd.UserId, osd.OfferId, ou.OfferName
  from dbo.offersentdetail as osd
    inner join (
      select OfferId = Offer1Id, OfferName, OfferExpiryDate
        from dbo.[Offer1] 
      union all 
      select OfferId = Offer2Id, OfferName, OfferExpiryDate
        from dbo.[Offer2] 
        ) as ou
    on osd.OfferId = ou.OfferId
```